# Specify Order numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy

I'm trying to put an array in the order of another array. For example, if I have:

```
arr1 = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
index = np.array([2, 1, 0])
```

My desired outcome, arr2, is ['c', 'b', 'a'], such that:

```
arr2[index[i]] == arr1[i]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply pass the selector array as index to the character array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr1 = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> index = np.array([2, 1, 0])
>>> arr1[index]
array(['c', 'b', 'a'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Comment: Perhaps there's an error in my code, but when I run this I get the following relationship, not the desired one:  arr2[i] == arr1[index[i]]

Comment: I think the issue might be a few lines before in the code -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[arr1[i] for i in index]
```

Comment: Doesn't return an array and is inefficient for numpy arrays. General rule: Don't treat numpy arrays as python lists. There is almost always a better way to do it with numpy builtins.